# Ramification of prime ideal in Kummer extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mu \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ lie above the rational prime $p\equiv 1 \text{ mod }n$, and let the prime ideal $\mathscr{P}\subset \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ have exponent $a$ in $(\mu)$.

Why is it then true that $\mathscr{P}$ has ramification index $\frac{n}{(a,n)}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n, \mu^{1/n})/\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$?

I would appreciate a proof as all references I can find seem to have proofs of thing that reference back to umpteen different earlier propositions, which is hard to read.

Comment: MO asked me to reask this here.

Comment: What is the ramification index of a prime over an element? Do you mean that in the decomposition of the ideal $(\mu)$ , the prime $\mathscr P$ has exponent $a$?

Comment: @Lubin Yes. I've edited to remove ambiguity.

Comment: Well, one more question, then: do you mean that $\mu|p$, i.e. that there is some $\beta\in\Bbb Z[\zeta_n]$ with $p=\mu\beta$?

Comment: @Lubin I do mean that.

Comment: I’m beginning to think that this is not true. Are you sure? My proposed counterexample would be for $n=p^2$, $\pi=\zeta-1$, and $\mu=\pi^p(1+\pi)=\pi^p\zeta$. But I need time to check it all over, and I’m going out to dinner soon, won’t be able to write anything up (or retreat in humiliating defeat) till tomorrow morning at the earliest.

Comment: @Lubin In case it makes a difference, this https://i.gyazo.com/86bd186242014b07ed7b4a28d82bba30.png halfway down is where the quesion arises from. Thank you for thinking about this.

Comment: Aha. That had a hypothesis that $p$ be $\equiv1\pmod m$, which my “counterexample” did not satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s my take on the situation: it seems to me to be a purely local question at $p$, so that it should be sufficient to translate everything to extensions of $\Bbb Q_p$.

Let’s do this translation, using the additional hypothesis that $n$ and $p$ are relatively prime: put $\mathfrak o=\Bbb Z_p[\zeta_n]$, ring of integers of an unramified extension $k$ of $\Bbb Q_p$. Use the standard additive valuation $v$ on $\Bbb Q_p$, so that $v(p)=1$, and extend to $k$. You have set $v(\mu)=a$, say $\mu=p^au$ where $u$ is a unit of $\mathfrak o$. Then $\mu^{1/n}=p^{a/n}u^{1/n}$. Now $\mathfrak o[u^{1/n}]$ is unramified over $\mathfrak o$: it just amounts to taking the $n$-th root of an element of $\mathfrak o/p\mathfrak o$, a finite field of characteristic $p$. But adjoining $p^{a/n}$ is cleasrly a totally ramified extension of degree $n/\!\gcd(a,n)$.